# Set default route on boot in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: networking, 16.04

I have two interfaces in my computer and this is how my routing table looks like when it boots up:

```
default via 192.168.80.1 dev enp4s1  proto static  metric 100
default 192.168.0.1 dev enp2s0  proto static  metric 101
```

However my Internet gateway is `192.168.0.1` so I won't have Internet connection each time my computer is rebooted, because the second network should be used for Internet access. I can set the default route manually and everything will work well:

```
sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

but I don't want to do that every time. How to configure default gateway permanently?

Comment: Tell the administrator of the DHCP server which is providing the address 192.168.80.nnn to stop assigning a non-functional default gateway? Or, if you are using static addresses, don't assign a default gateway to `enp4s1`?

Comment: Can't do that. One network is our internal company network, second one much faster is for Internet access.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I managed to solve this by myself simply by adding line

```
ip route add default via 192.168.0.1
```

to the `/etc/rc.local` script, so it gets executed every time automatically.

Note for everyone else, remember to change gateway IP address accordingly.

Comment: If you want to use the command on the console, you need `sudo` for this, and can also add the interface for that you want to add the default route, for example wifi: `sudo ip route add default via 192.168.0.1 dev wlp2s0` – and if you want to use rc.local, you first have to enable the rc.local service on systemd.

Answer (score 1):

Open the network manager and modify the connection. Click the networking icon in the tray then go to *Edit Connections* to open the dialog. In the dialog find your connection like Ethernet and press *Edit* and a dialog will appear. Go to the IPV4 tab and set your IP address or restore it to use DHCP which should find an IP address automatically.

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problems with connecting to both networks. My question is how to permanently add that static route I mentioned.